# SQL error -- how to use "(field IN (SELECT col from Table) OR (field IS NULL))" in Redshift

Tags: sql, null, amazon-redshift

I am getting an error in Redshift where logic dictates it shouldn't happen. The code is quite simple:

```
SELECT field1, field2
FROM table T
WHERE condition1
  AND condition2
  AND (T.field3 IN (SELECT col FROM T2) OR T.field3 IS NULL)
```

This produces an error with a context that reads context: query->a_last_plan()->m_locus == LocusXNode.

However, if I adapt the code above slightly and use:

```
SELECT field1, field2
FROM table T
WHERE condition1
  AND condition2
  AND (T.field3 IN ('a', 'b', 'c') OR T.field3 IS NULL)
```

Then things work. I can't resort to this subterfuge because the values that I need to compare T.field3 against are not fixed, they are indeed part of a table whose rows may change.

I already checked the data types and

```
(SELECT col FROM T2)
```

Has "col" with exactly the same data type as T.field3.

For now I'm resorting to an inelegant solution which is to add a fake 'null' value ('unik_null_value') into T2 and then use coalesce as such:

```
(coalesce(T.field3,'unik_null_value') IN (SELECT col FROM T2))
```

However this is quite a hack and adds an unwanted value in T2.
Any support is quite appreciated, thank you.

Comment: logic dictaes to read the manual and you will find it is not suported

Comment: Thanks @nbk -- any direction on possible elegant solutions?

Comment: use a (INNER) JOIN

Comment: INNER JOIN won't work since T2 doesn't have NULL values in it, as such the term (T.field3 is NULL) which I want to consider in the "OR" clause will not have any effect on the JOIN

Comment: UNION a second SELECT with `WHERE condition1
  AND condition2
  AND T.field3 IS NULL`

Comment: Thanks -- on a second thought, INNER JOIN does actually work if I do INNER JOIN T2 ON T.field3 = T2.col OR T.field3 IS NULL...   (and don't know how I didn't think about the UNION solution, obvious in hindsight). Thank you

Comment: i think the union will be faster

Comment: PS.: I wonder why the piece of code above in my original question, where the values are hardcoded in the query, works, but not when they are replaced by a SELECT that may even return exactly the same set of values

Comment: It was not implemented and the request wasn't programmed

Comment: can you use exists instead of in? AND (
            EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM T2
                WHERE T.field3 = t2.col
                )
            OR T.field3 IS NULL
            )